# Laptop keeps overheating while idle

Tags: cpu, fan, overheating

I've tried downloading Speedfan to up the fan speed, however in it I cannot change the speed of anything, and the CPU fan speed displays gibberish numbers.

Any help would gladly be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Have you exterminated the dust bunnies?

Comment: How do you know it is overheating? Those speedfan numbers are great for a core i7 laptop. Wish I could get mine to run anywhere close to that cool.